# Is it possible to have schema.xml per collection for Solr 8 with "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I think this can be done with the "ManagedIndexSchemaFactory" to have each schema for each collection via the schema API.

With SolrCloud on Solr 8, is it possible to have schema.xml per collection with "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"?

Best Regards,

Comment: you can create many configs and apply/use them separate per collection...every configset will have separate schema.xml

Comment: the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory or ClassicIndexSchemaFactory is not for maintaining separate schema.xml...but its a choice where you to go ahead with field defination way or let the solr define fields for you...

Comment: Thanks. The thing is in "ManagedIndexSchemaFactory", we update the field using the schema API. But for the "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory", we update directly the schema.xml.

Anyway, I got your idea that we can create seperate configset for each collection so we can get each schema.xml for each collection. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different set of configset with different schema.xml.

While creating the collection you can use the required config set out of the list of configset.

With this you can have different schema.xml for your collections.